# How to get guice to provide a unique instance with a provider?

Tags: java, guice

I have an object A that does some important loading. I use a provider for it. I have object B that needs A for its initialization. However in an object C I want to pass A, and B, properly prepared.

Would it be possible to get a provider to return the same instance all the time, or the guice module to keep that instance provided and stop right there?

Edited:

I have the following on the guice website with few explanation:

```
@Provides @Singleton
TransactionLog provideTransactionLog() {
  ...
}
```

**Is that the solution. Does the singleton apply to the provider or the provided. If it applies to the provider then, the solution would be to retain one instance and return it each time. But that would not work with a provide method.
Any help ?**

Answer (score 6):

Guice is very uniform in its core. Internally it is based completely on providers. Linked bindings, instance bindings, provider bindings, just-in-time bindings, `@Provides`-bindings - every kind of binding, in fact - will always generate a provider under the hood. Hence scope annotations can't be applied to providers, it just does not make sense. Scopes are *always* assigned to the actual injected objects, so you can be sure that if you put some binding into `@Singleton` scope, the actual injected object will *always* be the same, regardless of the kind of this binding.

So, each one of these bindings will always get you exactly the same unique object (of course, you can't put all of these bindings in your module; pick the one you like most):

```
bind(SomeDependency.class).to(SomeDependencyImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);

bind(SomeDependency.class).toInstance(new SomeDependencyImpl());

bind(SomeDependency.class).toProvider(() -> new SomeDependencyImpl()).in(Singleton.class);

public class SomeModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Provides @Singleton
    SomeDependency someDependencyImpl() {
        return new SomeDependencyImpl();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful explanation !!! Very clear. Although, there is just one point that I'm not sure to follow. The last example. Does it corresponds the case of implementing your own provider class?

Comment: @MaatDeamon, do you mean `@Provides` method? No, these methods are defined in modules. Providers only return new objects through their `get()` methods. The case with a custom provider is the second to last one, it uses Java 8 lambda syntax.

Comment: I code in scala so that syntax is ok for me I figured out the provider method. Only that in the guice doc. You can either have a provider method or a class that implement the provider interface. I thought you where doing the last with your last example.  I just don't understand to what correspond the last example you did. I just don't get. In a module you are suppose to have a configure method. Here you don't. The last example does not correspond to nothing that I know in guice.

Comment: @MaatDeamon, no, you got it wrong. Provider method are supposed to be defined in modules, see [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods). They are intended as a short alternative to full-fledged providers.

Comment: My bad. It's all good, thanks for your explanation all cleared up :)